# How to get first and last day in specific week in month

Tags: java, date, calendar, dayofweek, localdate

I need help to return the first day (and last day) of a given week, passing only the week of the month and the corresponding month and year.

I've already looked for a way to return using LocalDate or Calendar and haven't found it.

My Locale is PT-BR - First day of week is Sunday

Thanks in advance.

Ex:

```
Year 2021 - Month 7 (July) - Week 1 - First day: 1 - Last Day: 3
Year 2021 - Month 7 (July) - Week 2 - First day: 4 - Last Day: 10
Year 2021 - Month 7 (July) - Week 3 - First day: 11 - Last Day: 17
Year 2021 - Month 7 (July) - Week 4 - First day: 18 - Last Day: 24
Year 2021 - Month 7 (July) - Week 5 - First day: 25 - Last Day: 31
```

Comment: How would you do that without the year?

Comment: Doesn't the year have something to do with which days are in which weeks?  Your example works for July 2021.

Comment: What do you mean by `3` as the last day; do you mean Saturday? What is your time zone? Do you always consider the year as the current year?

Comment: Sorry, i forget year, I need to pass year too. And my locale is PT-BR.

Comment: Question updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your week calendar approach quite amusing to play with, came up with a method that receives two parameters (month and year) and builds up the week calendar of that month:

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer[]> getWeekCalendar(int month, int year) {
    Map<Integer, Integer[]> weekCalendar = new HashMap<>();
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year,month,1);
    int week = 1;
    LocalDate firstOfWeek = LocalDate.from(date);
    while (date.getMonth().equals(Month.of(month))) {
        //if it is a saturday, advance to the next week and register current week bounds
        if (date.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY)) {
            weekCalendar.put(week++, new Integer[]{firstOfWeek.getDayOfMonth(), date.getDayOfMonth()});
            firstOfWeek = LocalDate.from(date.plusDays(1L));
        }
        date = date.plusDays(1L);
    }
    //this one is necessary because the month may end on a Saturday
    if (firstOfWeek.getMonth().equals(Month.of(month))) {
        weekCalendar.put(week, new Integer[]{firstOfWeek.getDayOfMonth(), date.minusDays(1L).getDayOfMonth()});
    }
    return weekCalendar;
}
```

And a main class for testing purposes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int wantedMonth = 7;
    int wantedYear = 2021;
    Map<Integer, Integer[]> weekCalendar = getWeekCalendar(wantedMonth, wantedYear);
    weekCalendar.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> String.format("Year %d - Month %d (%s) - Week %d - First day: %d - Last day: %d", wantedYear, wantedMonth, Month.of(wantedMonth).name(), e.getKey(), e.getValue()[0], e.getValue()[1]))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

output:

```
Year 2021 - Month 7 (JULY) - Week 1 - First day: 1 - Last day: 3
Year 2021 - Month 7 (JULY) - Week 2 - First day: 4 - Last day: 10
Year 2021 - Month 7 (JULY) - Week 3 - First day: 11 - Last day: 17
Year 2021 - Month 7 (JULY) - Week 4 - First day: 18 - Last day: 24
Year 2021 - Month 7 (JULY) - Week 5 - First day: 25 - Last day: 31
```

Answer (score 4):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

1. Use `WeekFields.of(locale).getFirstDayOfWeek()` to find the first day of the week.
2. Use `TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(firstDayOfWeek)` to find the last day of the week.
3. Use `TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()` to find the last date of the month.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.time.temporal.WeekFields;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getWeeks(2021, 7, new Locale("pt", "BR")));

        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");

        System.out.println(getWeeks(2021, 2, new Locale("pt", "BR")));

        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");

        System.out.println(getWeeks(2021, 7, new Locale("en", "GB")));

        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");

        System.out.println(getWeeks(2021, 2, new Locale("en", "GB")));
    }

    static String getWeeks(int year, int month, Locale locale) {
        DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = WeekFields.of(locale).getFirstDayOfWeek();
        LocalDate firstDateOfMonth = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1);
        String monthName = Month.of(month).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);
        int lastDayOfMonth = firstDateOfMonth.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()).getDayOfMonth();

        int firstDay = 1;
        int lastDayOfFirstWeek = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1).with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(firstDayOfWeek))
                .getDayOfMonth();
        int lastDay = lastDayOfFirstWeek == 1 ? 7 : lastDayOfFirstWeek - 1;

        int i;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (i = 1; i <= lastDayOfMonth / 7; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("Year %d - Month %d (%s) - Week %d - First day: %d - Last Day: %d%n", year, month,
                    monthName, i, firstDay, lastDay));
            firstDay = lastDay + 1;
            lastDay += 7;
        }

        if (lastDayOfFirstWeek != 1 && lastDayOfMonth >= 28)
            sb.append(String.format("Year %d - Month %d (%s) - Week %d - First day: %d - Last Day: %d%n", year, month,
                    monthName, i, firstDay, lastDayOfMonth));

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Year 2021 - Month 7 (July) - Week 1 - First day: 1 - Last Day: 3
Year 2021 - Month 7 (July) - Week 2 - First day: 4 - Last Day: 10
Year 2021 - Month 7 (July) - Week 3 - First day: 11 - Last Day: 17
Year 2021 - Month 7 (July) - Week 4 - First day: 18 - Last Day: 24
Year 2021 - Month 7 (July) - Week 5 - First day: 25 - Last Day: 31

---------------------------------------------------------
Year 2021 - Month 2 (February) - Week 1 - First day: 1 - Last Day: 6
Year 2021 - Month 2 (February) - Week 2 - First day: 7 - Last Day: 13
Year 2021 - Month 2 (February) - Week 3 - First day: 14 - Last Day: 20
Year 2021 - Month 2 (February) - Week 4 - First day: 21 - Last Day: 27
Year 2021 - Month 2 (February) - Week 5 - First day: 28 - Last Day: 28

---------------------------------------------------------
Year 2021 - Month 7 (July) - Week 1 - First day: 1 - Last Day: 4
Year 2021 - Month 7 (July) - Week 2 - First day: 5 - Last Day: 11
Year 2021 - Month 7 (July) - Week 3 - First day: 12 - Last Day: 18
Year 2021 - Month 7 (July) - Week 4 - First day: 19 - Last Day: 25
Year 2021 - Month 7 (July) - Week 5 - First day: 26 - Last Day: 31

---------------------------------------------------------
Year 2021 - Month 2 (February) - Week 1 - First day: 1 - Last Day: 7
Year 2021 - Month 2 (February) - Week 2 - First day: 8 - Last Day: 14
Year 2021 - Month 2 (February) - Week 3 - First day: 15 - Last Day: 21
Year 2021 - Month 2 (February) - Week 4 - First day: 22 - Last Day: 28
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/v4cwED)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

## Annual calendar of weeks

To expand on the [correct Answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68693374/642706), let’s get the weekly calendar for a year. And for our week, let’s use a third-party class designed to represent a span-of-time of days. We collect a map of month as key and list of weeks as value. From that map we can retrieve any particular week.

### *ThreeTen-Extra* library, `LocalDateRange` class

Add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. This gives us the `LocalDateRange` class to represent a span of time as a pair of `LocalDate` objects. This class provides many convenient methods such as `abuts`, `contains`, and so on, likely to be helpful when you are working with weeks.

Specify a `Year` and a `Locale`. From the locale we determine the first day-of-week as shown in [Answer by Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68693374/642706).

### Loop each month, then each week

We loop every month of the year, using an array of [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) objects returned by the [`Month.values`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html#values()) method on this [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). We combine each month with the year to get a [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) object.

For each `YearMonth`, we get the first day of the month. Then we move back in time to get the first day-of-week ([`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html)), or use the same date if it is indeed our desired day-of-week. A [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) moves us along the timeline. You can write your own `TemporalAdjuster` implementation, but we can find one already written for our needs here: [`TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#previousOrSame(java.time.DayOfWeek)).

Then we loop to calculate each week of the month, making a `LocalDateRange` from the pair of `LocalDate` objects for start and end of each week. We collect those `LocalDateRange` objects into a [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html), a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html).

We report our results by adding each `YearMonth` as the key to a [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) ([`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html)), with the value being our `NavigableSet` of `LocalDateRange`.

### Example code

```java
package work.basil.datetime;

import org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange;

import java.time.*;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.time.temporal.WeekFields;
import java.util.*;

public final class WeeklyCalendar {
    public static final NavigableMap < YearMonth, List < LocalDateRange > > calculate ( final Year year , final Locale locale ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( year );
        DayOfWeek startOfWeek = WeekFields.of( Objects.requireNonNull( locale ) ).getFirstDayOfWeek();

        NavigableMap < YearMonth, List < LocalDateRange > > navMap = new TreeMap <>();

        TemporalAdjuster adjuster = TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( startOfWeek );
        for ( Month month : Month.values() ) {
            List < LocalDateRange > weeks = new ArrayList <>();
            YearMonth yearMonth = year.atMonth( month );
            LocalDate start = yearMonth.atDay( 1 ).with( adjuster );
            LocalDate end = start.plusWeeks( 1 );
            do {
                LocalDateRange week = LocalDateRange.of( start , end );
                weeks.add( week );
                // Set up next loop.
                start = start.plusWeeks( 1 );
                end = start.plusWeeks( 1 );
            } while ( ! YearMonth.from( end ).isAfter( yearMonth ) );
            navMap.put( yearMonth , weeks );
        }

        return Collections.unmodifiableNavigableMap( navMap );  // Generally best to return immutable values.
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
Year year = Year.of( 2021 );
Locale locale = new Locale( "pt" , "BR" );
NavigableMap < YearMonth, List < LocalDateRange > > map = WeeklyCalendar.calculate( year , locale );

LocalDateRange weekOneOfMarch2021 = map.get( YearMonth.of( 2021 , Month.MARCH ) ).get( 0 );  // Lists use annoying zero-based counting, index number.
```

When run.

> map = {2021-01=[2020-12-27/2021-01-03, 2021-01-03/2021-01-10, 2021-01-10/2021-01-17, 2021-01-17/2021-01-24, 2021-01-24/2021-01-31], 2021-02=[2021-01-31/2021-02-07, 2021-02-07/2021-02-14, 2021-02-14/2021-02-21, 2021-02-21/2021-02-28], 2021-03=[2021-02-28/2021-03-07, 2021-03-07/2021-03-14, 2021-03-14/2021-03-21, 2021-03-21/2021-03-28], 2021-04=[2021-03-28/2021-04-04, 2021-04-04/2021-04-11, 2021-04-11/2021-04-18, 2021-04-18/2021-04-25], 2021-05=[2021-04-25/2021-05-02, 2021-05-02/2021-05-09, 2021-05-09/2021-05-16, 2021-05-16/2021-05-23, 2021-05-23/2021-05-30], 2021-06=[2021-05-30/2021-06-06, 2021-06-06/2021-06-13, 2021-06-13/2021-06-20, 2021-06-20/2021-06-27], 2021-07=[2021-06-27/2021-07-04, 2021-07-04/2021-07-11, 2021-07-11/2021-07-18, 2021-07-18/2021-07-25], 2021-08=[2021-08-01/2021-08-08, 2021-08-08/2021-08-15, 2021-08-15/2021-08-22, 2021-08-22/2021-08-29], 2021-09=[2021-08-29/2021-09-05, 2021-09-05/2021-09-12, 2021-09-12/2021-09-19, 2021-09-19/2021-09-26], 2021-10=[2021-09-26/2021-10-03, 2021-10-03/2021-10-10, 2021-10-10/2021-10-17, 2021-10-17/2021-10-24, 2021-10-24/2021-10-31], 2021-11=[2021-10-31/2021-11-07, 2021-11-07/2021-11-14, 2021-11-14/2021-11-21, 2021-11-21/2021-11-28], 2021-12=[2021-11-28/2021-12-05, 2021-12-05/2021-12-12, 2021-12-12/2021-12-19, 2021-12-19/2021-12-26]}
>
> weekOneOfMarch2021 = 2021-02-28/2021-03-07

Notice how `LocalDateRange#toString` uses the standard format of start date, then SOLIDUS `/`, then end date.

## Annual overlap

Notice that we start with days in the previous year. And we do not include some of the last days of the calendar-year.

### Half-Open

Notice that the weeks here are defined using Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This is usually the best approach in defining a span-of-time. I recommend using this approach consistently throughout your codebase to keep the logic consistent and thereby avoid errors and confusion.

### Fully-Closed

However, if you insist on fully-closed approach, the `LocalDateRange` class can support that. See the [`LocalDateRange.ofClosed`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html#ofClosed(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalDate)) method.

### Use at your own risk

I quickly whipped up this code just now. So no guarantees. Verify the logic, and perform your own tests.

### ISO 8601 weeks

Be aware that there are several ways to define a week. Some industries commonly use a particular definition.

There is an international standard that is growing in popularity: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). That [standard defines weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) as Monday being the first day of the week, and week # 1 containing the first Thursday of the calendar year. Therefore a year is made of either 52 or 53 complete weeks of 7 days each.

The *ThreeTen-Extra* library offers a class to represent ISO 8601 weeks: [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no single function to get the week of the month.

I put together a method to calculate the week of the month.  Here are the test results from one of my many test runs.

```
Week 1 of July 2021 is 1 - 3
Week 2 of July 2021 is 4 - 10
Week 3 of July 2021 is 11 - 17
Week 4 of July 2021 is 18 - 24
Week 5 of July 2021 is 25 - 31
Week 6 of July 2021 is 0 - 0
Week 1 of August 2021 is 1 - 7
Week 2 of August 2021 is 8 - 14
```

I created a `LocalDate` based on the year and month.  I did some date arithmetic to get the Sunday day of the month and Saturday day of the month for a week of the month.

Here's the code.  I tested it for July and August 2021.  It may work for other months.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class DatesFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DatesFinder df = new DatesFinder();
        int[] days = df.findDays(2021, 7, 1);
        System.out.println("Week 1 of July 2021 is " + days[0] + " - " + days[1]);
        days = df.findDays(2021, 7, 2);
        System.out.println("Week 2 of July 2021 is " + days[0] + " - " + days[1]);
        days = df.findDays(2021, 7, 3);
        System.out.println("Week 3 of July 2021 is " + days[0] + " - " + days[1]);
        days = df.findDays(2021, 7, 4);
        System.out.println("Week 4 of July 2021 is " + days[0] + " - " + days[1]);
        days = df.findDays(2021, 7, 5);
        System.out.println("Week 5 of July 2021 is " + days[0] + " - " + days[1]);
        days = df.findDays(2021, 7, 6);
        System.out.println("Week 6 of July 2021 is " + days[0] + " - " + days[1]);
        days = df.findDays(2021, 8, 1);
        System.out.println("Week 1 of August 2021 is " + days[0] + " - " + days[1]);
        days = df.findDays(2021, 8, 2);
        System.out.println("Week 2 of August 2021 is " + days[0] + " - " + days[1]);
    }
    
    public int[] findDays(int year, int month, int weekNumber) {
        LocalDate date =  LocalDate.of(year, month, 1);
        int weekday = date.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
        // weekday is 1 - Monday to 7 - Sunday.
        // convert to 0 - Sunday.
        weekday = weekday % 7;
        
        LocalDate sundayDate = date.minusDays(weekday);
        int dayIncrement = (weekNumber - 1) * 7;
        if (dayIncrement > 0) {
            sundayDate = sundayDate.plusDays(dayIncrement);
        }
        
        int lowDay = sundayDate.getDayOfMonth();
        LocalDate saturdayDate = sundayDate.plusDays(6L);
        int highDay = saturdayDate.getDayOfMonth();
//      System.out.println(date + " " + sundayDate + " " + lowDay + " " + highDay);
        
        // Test for beginning of month
        if (sundayDate.getMonth().compareTo(date.getMonth()) < 0) {
            lowDay = 1;
        }
        
        // Test for end of month
        if (saturdayDate.getMonth().compareTo(date.getMonth()) > 0) {
            LocalDate nextMonth = date.plusMonths(1L);
            nextMonth = nextMonth.minusDays(1L);
            highDay = nextMonth.getDayOfMonth();
        }
        
        // Test for outside of month (weekNumber too high)
        if (sundayDate.getMonth().compareTo(date.getMonth()) > 0) {
            lowDay = 0;
            highDay = 0;
        }

        int[] output = new int[2];
        output[0] = lowDay;
        output[1] = highDay;
        
        return output;
    }

}
```